# Why is the direct query limitation mentioned when the new preview feature supports DQ based connection to shared dafaset?

Tags: powerbi

I can connect to shared dataset using live connection.

Suppose I want to use more than 1 shared dataset, or want to add additional data sources along with shared dataset, then there is a new feature recently launched for such functionality where-in the connection changes from live to direct query mode.

However, this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-many-to-many-relationships#considerations-and-limitations mentions Power BI dataset as a limitation.

I want to ask- what exactly is the limitation they are referring to? Does it mean that - when there is a m:m relationship in a model, and if we use DQ to connect to that model with the intention to also connect to another data source (or model) in import or DQ mode, then this isn't supported when the dataset we have connected to has got a m:m relationship?

Does the limitation apply when connecting to another dataset in live mode?

Answer (score 0):

as per your link:

> The following Live Connect **(multidimensional)** sources can't be used
> with composite models

Analysis Services can host both tabular and multidimensional models (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/comparing-tabular-and-multidimensional-solutions-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions). The way I understand the article you posted, you cannot use composite models (and m:m) with the multidimensional models.

I've connected to the tabular models hosted in AAS via DirectQuery (adding tables and m:m relationships) and never had issues, so if you have a tabular model these limitations shouldn't apply to you